# MYSQL - Unable to change 'old_passwords' variable

Tags: mysql, password

I have full access to a 'MYSQL 5.0.27-community-nt-log' database one of our new updates for a core app requires PHP 5.4, after installing and configuring I'm stuck at the error regarding old vs. new passwords.

I've followed every thread I can find and I'm pretty sure I understand the process:

1. Disable 'old_passwords'
2. Reset the password to the new 41 encryption

But I cannot seem to get 'old_passwords' to be set to 'OFF'. Logging in as root I've tried the following:

- I've removed it from the my.cnf file (I've also tried setting it to '0', 'False' etc)
- Manually setting it in the query browser both globally and session
- Turning the option on/off in MYSQL administrator

and restarted the service but 'show variables like 'old_passwords' always reports as 'ON'.

Changing the password still remains at a 16 length.

I'm sure once I'm able to turn this variable off I should be fine, Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 3 additional suggestions (choose one):

- Downgrade the PHP drivers (which understand the 16 character encrypted password)
- Upgrade to the latest MySQL (where you can set `old_password=1` from inception)
- Change all the passwords in `mysql.user` to 41 character encrypted password format

Whatever you do, do not use the MD5 function to make new passwords. Use the PASSWORD function. It is very different from MD5:

The password function [**PASSWORD**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function is the equivalent of

```
SET @my_new_password = 'WhateverIWantAsThePassword';
SELECT CONCAT('*',UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1(@my_new_password))))) MySQLPWDHASH;
```

I learned that like 2 years ago from [**this PalominoDB Blog Post**](https://blog.pythian.com/hashing-algorithm-in-mysql-password-2/).

You can QA the PASSWORD function with [**OLD_PASSWORD**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_old-password) function. Compare the output of `SELECT PASSWORD(@my_new_password);` WITH `SELECT OLD_PASSWORD(@my_new_password);`.

Comment: It's been a while but during that upgrade I ended up doing a combination,  going to a latest MySQL as well as PHP and updating the required passwords.

Comment: Sorry, the PalominoDB post no longer exists (company was bought by Pythian)

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to return earlier but none of the answers provided worked and after a few days of playing around I eventually bit the bullet and upgraded the MySQL server to the latest version.

So in the end I never found a workable solution but the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set `old_passwords=1` lower down in your my.cnf file, the last setting takes priority.  So check the full length of your my.cnf for another line that sets this variable.

Comment: Checked and re-checked, line by line.  It is not mentioned anywhere.  I have noticed, if I check the box in 'MYSQL Administrator' it does add the entry, but with no value.  Setting the value to 0 or 1 or removing it completely makes no difference to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was an error in log:

> 190122  4:39:09 [Warning] mysql.user table is not updated to new
>   password format; Disabling new password usage until
>   mysql_fix_privilege_tables is run

The  `mysql_fix_privilege_tables` was replaced with mysql_upgrade in MySQL 5.1.
For my Mariadb 5.5 I ran to fix it:

```
mysql_upgrade --force
```

And restarted the service.