# Probable update error to mysql 5.7.21

Tags: mysql

I have a VM with Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. I use it for wordpress sites, so it haves mysql, nginx and php. I migrated from Azure to Vultr. For doing so I backed up all the databases in Azure and restored them into my VM at Vultr.

That was a couple of months ago. Everything was working fine until today, when I wanted to add a new wordpress site. As usual I started by configuring the database for mysql, so I tried to loging to mysql and my issues started. A problem with the socket appeared, and then I ran `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` to be able to access mysql.

I was able to access it and to fix my issue I ran `update user set plugin="mysql_native_password";` and exited mysql. After struggling a while some other sockets errors appeared.

Reading on StackOverflow an upgrade was recommended, therefore I updated my database and now this is my current issue. I can login with `mysql -u root -p`. But, when I enter `use mysql;` I get: `ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

Then, when I run `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxxxx';` i get `ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted`

The `password` column doesn't exists in the `user` table, so instead of the previous statement I used `update mysql.user set authentication_string=password('xxxxxxx') where user='root';` and I got `ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.` so it seams to me that I'm in a dead end.

This is my current error when I run `mysql_upgrade --force -uroot -p`...`mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1862: Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client that supports expired passwords. while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.`

I appreciate any help you can give me.

*UPDATE*

Looking at the user.frm files I noticed that the column that the `is_role` column is the extra column in my user table. I tried to edit the user.frm file but I wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: Have you run `mysql_upgrade` after the upgrade? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155026/mysql-8-0-11-cant-find-mysql-infoschema-after-update-from-5-7/51155179#51155179

Answer (score 0):

You must be operating in some restricted mode

[The MySQL Documentation for ALTER USER says the following](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-user.html):

> Password expiration for an account affects the corresponding row of the mysql.user system table: The server sets the password_expired column to 'Y'.
>
> A client session operates in restricted mode if the account password has been expired. In restricted mode, operations performed within the session result in an error until the user establishes a new account password:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 1;
> ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must SET PASSWORD before executing this statement
>
> mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new_password');
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
>
> mysql> SELECT 1;
> +---+
> | 1 |
> +---+
> | 1 |
> +---+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

## SUGGESTION : Try the aforementioned code

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new_password');
```

If this does not works due to [**old_passwords**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_old_passwords), do the hash algorithm manually

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD = CONCAT('*',UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('new_password')))));
```

[I learned about this hash algorithm from PalominoDB (last bought by Pythian)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50610/mysql-unable-to-change-old-passwords-variable/55635#55635).

Comment: Thanks for your respond @RolandoMySQLDBA...I tried both commands but the result is the same. You are right that `SELECT 1;` will return an error, in my case `ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`

Comment: I tried `SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new_password');` and the error is `ERROR 1805 (HY000): Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted` and in the case of `mysql> SET PASSWORD = CONCAT('*',UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('new_password')))));` throws `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT('*',UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('new_password')))))' at line 1`. My assumption is that I broke something. Do you have any additional recommendation?

Comment: What version of MySQL did you upgrade to ??? (My guess is 8.0 because the column count for `mysql.user` table is 45, 43, 42, 39, 37 in MySQL 5.7, 5.6, 5.5, 5.1, 5.0 (See my old post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203038/restoring-xtrabackup-from-mysql-5-6-to-mysql-5-7/203044#203044))

Comment: MySQL 8.0 probably has 46 because of the presence of the password_expired column. Please make sure you are using MySQL 8,0 client because it would expect 46 columns.

Comment: I am sorry I have not worked with MySQL 8.0 as of yet, so I can only help but so much in this case.

Comment: If you did upgrade to MySQL 8.0, you probably need to run `mysql_upgrade --upgrade-system-tables` (See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html#option_mysql_upgrade_upgrade-system-tables)

Comment: Thanks RolandoMySQLDBA. These are my versions:
`mysql-client-5.7/now 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]......mysql-client-core-5.7/now 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1].......mysql-common/now 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 all [installed,upgradable to: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]....mysql-server-5.7/now 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1].....mysql-server-core-5.7/now 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]`

Comment: I created a working copy of my database latest backup and I noticed that the user table in the broken instance have the `is_role` column in the user table, meanwhile the working instance doesn't have that column. Given that my error is that the user table have 46 columns instead of 45. I tried to edit my user.frm file but didn't got it. Can you think in something new knowing this?

Comment: Roles were introduced in MySQL 8.0. Somehow you upgraded to it. You must still be using MySQL 5.7 client and accessing MySQL 8.0 now. That must be what’s going on.

Comment: How can I update my client to MySQL 8.0?